# I want my home page to visually be separated into two full view screens, full heigth

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I'm currently using the markup shown below. It does show the first part in full height, regardless of resolution (that's the main point), but when I scroll to the second half, there is a huge gap of empty space. How do I get rid of that gap and made the transition seamless (I use anchor-style to navigate to second half)

```css
.first-half {height:50vh; background: red;}
.second-half {height:50vh; background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="first-half">
  content
</div>
<div class="second-half">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any gaps here: http://jsfiddle.net/xv114zzt/ Can you reproduce the issue using jsfiddle?

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ska94fgq/?

Comment: Drydem, I can't simulate full screen height on jfiddle, at least I don't see if it's working or not. j08691 - yes, that's it, no joy tho, maybe I have a conflicting code, let me check

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* For function purposes */
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

div[class^="fh-"] {
    height: 100%;
}

/* For design purposes */
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.fh-1 {
    background: red;
}

.fh-2 {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="fh-1">content</div>
<div class="fh-2">content</div>
```

`height: 100%` on `html` and `body` is there to make sure that when we put a 100% height on the `div`s, it will take the entire height. The rest is some basic styling to clearly see the separations.